# How to search for a string and replace entire line using powershell? (If string NOT matched, need to create a new line with the content)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Sample.txt:

```
SQL.test = True
wer.vul = 1
temp_RTE = False
user_admin = no
```

In the above text file, I want to search for a string `"test"` and replace entire line with `"SQL.test = False"` using Windows Powershell script. If `"test"` text is not matched, need to add `"SQL.test = False"` line to that file.

I have tried [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2134e5fc-5466-4cfb-8e3e-7e3a47a7cf25/powershell-find-and-replace-portion-of-text-in-file?forum=winserverpowershell). But I am unable to solve.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
$text = 'test'
$found = $false
$infile = '.\a.txt'
$outfile = '.\b.txt'
Get-Content -Path $infile | % { 
    if ($_ -match $text)
    {
        $found = $true
        "SQL.test = False"
    }
    else
    {
        $_
    }
} | Out-File -filepath $outfile
if (!$found)
{
    "SQL.test = False" |Out-File -filepath $outfile -Append
}
```

This can be optimized further, I'm sure.

Basically what this does is use `Get-Content` to retrieve each line in the text file, and pipe them to `Select-String`.
If the text is found, the line is changed, if not, the original line is returned.
If the text is not found, then it's appended.

If the text is found the output is:

```
SQL.test = False
wer.vul = 1 
temp_RTE = False 
user_admin = no
```

else

```
wer.vul = 1 
temp_RTE = False 
user_admin = no 
SQL.test = False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i run this code, its replacing entire content with the text. I want to 1. If text found replace the entire line (remaining lines should be present). 2. If text not found, should append the text. Please give any clue to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = gc .\test.txt
$c | %{ if ( $_ -match "test") { "SQL.test = False" } else {"SQL.test = True"} }
```

will output

```
SQL.test = False
SQL.test = True
SQL.test = True
SQL.test = True
```

for input file

```
SQL.test = True
wer.vul = 1
temp_RTE = False
user_admin = no
```

if you meant add "sqlxxxx" to that line simply use the concat + operator

```
$c | %{ if ( $_ -match "test") { "SQL.test = False" } else {$_ + " SQL.test = True"} }
```

will output

```
SQL.test = False
wer.vul = 1 SQL.test = True
temp_RTE = False SQL.test = True
user_admin = no SQL.test = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work for you :)

```
# Get content from the original file
$TXT = Get-Content "C:\temp\New Text Document.txt"
#Path to new file
$NewTXT="C:\temp\newTxt.txt"
$i=0
$TXT|ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match "test")
        {($_ -replace $_,"SQL.test = False") | Out-File $NewTXT -Append
        $i++ #increment}
      else
        {$_ | Out-File $NewTXT -Append}
}

If ($i -eq 0) #if $i=0 no "test" found, need to add new line "SQL.test = False"
    {"SQL.test = False" | Out-File $NewTXT -Append}
```